# Determine size in kb of a BLOB column in DB2

Tags: size, db2, blob

File table contains - File_Id and File_data(BLOB)

how can I know the size of the binary file stored in File_data column. `length` function gives the length of file but how to know the size in KB.

Comment: divide the resulting length by 1024?

Comment: @Peter it means length gives size in bytes. Is that the actual size?

Comment: @nectar, Yes, LENGTH gives actual data size stored in that record.

Answer (score 14):

This gives a number in bytes, devide it by 1024 to get size in KB.

```
Select sum(BIGINT(length(blob_column)))
from table;
```

Answer (score -3):

BLOB *Length* is not quite the same as *size*.

You first need to answer NO to all of these questions for it to be the file size:

1. Is the BLOB column declared as COMPACT?
2. Is the table data compressed? (Off by default)

Also consider LOB locator overhead.

Basically the answer is, that you can't really 100% determine the BLOB / actual file size from the column via length method.

Comment: i don't understand why this is downvoted? is the compact-ness of the column not to be considered?

Comment: I quess the people who read it didn't understood what i meant with my original answer. My point was that you can only use length of the blob column IF the table is not compressed and the column is not COMPACT.

Comment: `COMPACT`ness of a LOB column has nothing to do with the length of the value stored in it.

Comment: @Reigo, I believe the compression is done in disk level, so for clients, data is always seen as uncompressed.