# Can we decrease CLOB\BLOB size after increasing?

Tags: db2

Am getting SQL0302N error when updating a document. So I got suggestion to increase BLOB\CLOB size. I want to see how much is current size in my db2 table. How can I do that?

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAHQR_8.4.3/com.ibm.administeringcm.doc/trs20002.htm

This link will explain more on what steps am trying to do. I have plan to run the procedure present in link before that I wan to check size.

Comment: Did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922479/determine-size-in-kb-of-a-blob-column-in-db2

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher: As per the link provided by me  I have to run procedure which will increase the BLOB\CLOB size on complete database. But link provided by you is explaining for a particular table. Can you please help me on how to see it for complete db

Comment: Sorry - you are asking about decreasing in the headline - you are asking about the size of a table in the text and about the complete db in your comment. So what do you really want to do?